# Dynamic_cast not showing the right object type

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast

I spent a lot of time trying to figure out why my code displays "Derived3" after I run it and I cannot understand it at all. From what I have read here on many posts, dynamic_cast should somehow say whether a pointer (in this case b) is (in this case) Derived2 or not. However, it passed the condition and when it should print out the display() function from Derived2 class, it strangely displayes the one from the Derived3 class. I am just wondering why the program displays "Derived 3" instead of not showing anything, since b pointer is clearly not pointing to a Derived2 object.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Base
{
    int b;
    public:
    virtual void display()
    {
        cout<<"Base"<<endl;
    }
};

class Derived: virtual public Base{
public:
    void display()
    {
        cout<<"Derived"<<endl;
    }
};

class Derived2: virtual public Base{
public:
    void display()
    {
        cout<<"Derived 2"<<endl;
    }
};

class Derived3:public Derived,public Derived2{
public:
    void display()
    {
        cout<<"Derived 3"<<endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Base *b = new Derived3();
    Derived2 *aux = dynamic_cast<Derived2*>(b);
    if(aux)
    {
        aux->display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

However, after editing the code a little bit, it works as it should be.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Base
{
    int b;
    public:
    virtual void display()
    {
        cout<<"Base"<<endl;
    }
};

class Derived: public Base{
public:
    void display()
    {
        cout<<"Derived"<<endl;
    }
};

class Derived2: public Base{
public:
    void display()
    {
        cout<<"Derived 2"<<endl;
    }
};

class Derived3:public Base{
public:
    void display()
    {
        cout<<"Derived 3"<<endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Base *b = new Derived3();
    Derived2 *aux = dynamic_cast<Derived2*>(b);
    if(aux)
    {
        aux->display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As a side note, if you do not want a "Is-a" relationship, use composition instead of inheritance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inheritance is a *"Is-a"* relationship.

Every `Derived` is both a `Derived` and a `Base`. By that pattern, every `Derived3` is a `Derived3`, a `Derived2`, a `Derived` and a `Base` at the same time.

It would thus not make sense for that cast to fail.

The output is then finally the result of a normal virtual function call on a `Derived2*`. This is no different than in the most trivial example of inheritance, like in this snippet:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    virtual void fun() const {
        std::cout << 'A';
    }
};

struct B : A {
    void fun() const {
        std::cout << 'B';
    }
};

int main () {
    const A &a = B();
    a.fun();            // prints 'B'
}
```

If you have a pointer or reference to some base class, a virtual function call will resolve to the actual type of the object it is called on. In your case, that's a `Derived2*` pointing to a child-class of type `Derived3`, so the function is looked up in the latter.

Keep in mind that the `dynamic_cast` only changes the type of the pointer, not the type of the object it points to!

Comment: (Also, as always, because the standard says so, but I guessed that was not the point of the question.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I still cannot understand why it displays Derived 3. I understood that every Derived 3 is a derived 2, a derived and a base, but I don't understand why the b pointer which is not a derived 2 calls the display method from derived 3 class.

Comment: @TheDarkKnight Edited in some extra example and explanation, does that help?

Comment: It's getting really late here and I was really on this problem for so so long I can't really concentrate anymore... I understand what you wrote in the example, but based on that principle, my code shoudn't display anything on the screen, I explained it the the second code I posted. There it works as it should be. I guess it's something related to that virtual inheritance which fixed the diamond issue but messes with dynamic_cast...

Comment: @TheDarkKnight In your second piece of code, `Derived3` does not inherit from `Derived2`, so the cast fails as it should. `Derived3` no longer is a `Derived2` after the change.

Comment: So basically the dynamic_cast does not convert anything? It just tells you if b is or not a derived 2 and the aux still points to derived 3 afterall?

Comment: @TheDarkKnight Yes; as I wrote in my last comment, the `dynamic_cast` just changes the type of the pointer, not of the type object it points to. (It does that after checking if this is a valid cast, it's mostly useful for downcasting like `dynamic_cast<Derived*>(somePointerToBase)`; which, in turn, is a hint your design is broken.)

Comment: so what I understood is that dynamic_cast works like this. If there is no relationship between the Base pointer, let's say from my example "b" and the derived one it won't display anything(like I did with my second code). If there is a relationship between the Base pointer and  and the derived one like it was in my first code the pointer will still point to the derived 3 and not convert to derived 2.  And the only way it works to tell you exactly whether the b is a derived type or not is actually to have a pointer initialized and pointing to the exact derived class you're checking in <>

Comment: @TheDarkKnight It's not flawless wording, but I think you got that cast part mostly right. Do you want an example on how to get `"Derived 2"` as the output from a `Base*`?

Comment: Thanks, yes, I would want and example. A modification to my first code so that it will show derived 2 will be ideal.  Thanks for your help, I really appreciate!

Comment: @TheDarkKnight You can just slice away the `Derived3`-part of the object by making a new, actual `Derived2` object and call the method on that. See https://wandbox.org/permlink/OH6sRaUZI0cb6TV6 And you are welcome, that's why we are here. :)

Answer (score 0):

> However, it passed the condition and when it should print out the display() function from Derived2 class, it strangely displayes the one from the Derived3 class.

That's because of dynamic dispatch. Remember that `display()` is declared to be a `virtual` member function. It continues to be a `virtual` member function for all the derived classes.

Even though you cast the pointer from `Base*` to `Derived*`, the underlying object is still a `Derived3`. Hence, the dynamic dispatch mechanism calls `Derived3::display()`.

`Derived3::display()` will also be called if you use:

```
Base *b = new Derived3();
b->display();
```

Comment: @R Sahu And yeah, since display() is a virtual method, shouldn't be normal for the program to call the one pointed by the *b pointer, why seems to be Derived2? Why is the object still considered as Derived 3 if I'm asking if it is Derived 2?

Comment: @TheDarkKnight, it is a `Derived2` also by virtue of it being a `Derived3`. The underlying object continues to be `Derived3` object. Using `dynamic_cast` to get a `Derived2*` to the object does not change that.

Comment: @R Sahu So you're saying that based on the design of the inheritance, even if they were 5,6,7 Derived classes from every one like this : Derived 1 from Base, Derived 2 from Derived 1, Derived 3 from Derived 2 etc. the underlying object will always be the last one in this case Derived 7? I mean, dynamic_cast works as I want only if I have multiple classes derived from the same base like : Derived  from Base, Derived 1 from Base etc. Because that's when the display function prints out the answer as it should be.

Comment: @TheDarkKnight, the underlying object will always be of the type you construct. If you use `Base* b = new Derived6;`, the underlying object will be `Derived6`. Just because `Derived7` is derived from `Derived6`, does not mean that the constructed object will always be of type `Derived7`.